# Set focus in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, focus

ALL,

I'm working with Eclipse on the RHEL7.

When I double click on the file - the file is opened inside the editor, but the focus is not transitioned to the editor. I have to click inside the editor to give it focus.

Can I give the focus to the editor when the file is shown?

Project is in C++.

TIA!

P.S.: Google refer me to the question about programmatically set the focus to program created in Eclipse, hence the question.

Comment: I think you need to better justify the C++ tag. This looks more like a problem with the tools you just happen to be using to write and build c++ code.

Comment: @user4581301, the tag is here to say that I'm working with the C++ Eclipse and not the JAVA or any other language. And  yes, the problem is with the Eclipse itself, but with C++ Eclipse.

Comment: You say you double-click on the file.  Where are you seeing this file to double-click on it?  I'm not familiar with the C++ environment in Eclipse. What underlying version of Eclipse are you using?  Pressing F12 (activate-editor) might be useful.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr, yes the editor opens up and I do see the source code. However I have to click inside the editor to give it focus. And I'm using the latest version of Eclipse.